# Android voice recorder with unlimited recording time

Tags: voice-recording

I've tried the [Bighand](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bighand.android) and [Tape-a-Talk Voice Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.markus.droesser.tapeatalk) apps, but both only seem to record continuously for about 1 hour.  Is there an Android app which will allow me to record until I run out of storage space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [PCM Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kohei.android.pcmrecorder&hl=en) and it will record until it consumes entire storage space.  Also, I am able to use the phone for other tasks and PCM Recorder seems to keep recording in background, which is cool. I can even lock the phone and there by switch off the display which makes the drain on battery to very minimal, in par with the stock voice recorder application.

Comment: I've been testing this over the last 2 days and did a total of 3 recordings.  Recording 1 stopped after 6 hours and was around 2.1Gb.  Recording 2 stopped after 6 hours and was around 2.1Gb.  Recording 3 I manually stopped after 3 hours and noticed that it only recorded audio in the first hour, the remaining 2 hours were silent.  So it seems that PCM Recorder does not consume the entire storage space...  I have a 16Gb card, and 2.1Gb twice only takes up 4.2Gb.  So why is it stopping after 6 hours or 2.1Gb?

Comment: I have used PCM recorder for recording 8 hours session. The recording was stopped my me as my need was over. Also the Google's Play web page for this app says 'Records no time limit'. Hence this should be either a bug or some other issue. Can you send your observation to the developer of the app and share with us what he/she says?

Comment: Will do.  I've found that you can get about 18 hours at the lowest hz, but only 6 hours at the highest hz... I'll pass on a note to the developers to find out why they have `Records no time limit` in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Dictadroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softeight.android.dictadroid.full), the highest ranked voice recorder on Google Play. Just set the recording capacity setting to "Unlimited".

Comment: This app is incompatible with my phone according to play.google.com.  Putting that aside for a moment, does this app also have a 6 hour or 2.1Gb limit per recording?

Answer (score 0):

I've not known and used any voice recorder on Android except [Smart Voice Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrwq.recorder&hl=en). It's got good ratings too.